# Convert label in line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling

Is there a method to convert the text of labels in lines? I think infact that the letters can be hypothetically transformed in lines, for simplify the view in other kinds of gis.

Comment: Convert labels to annotation and have a look at https://geonet.esri.com/thread/19792

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has a [VBA script](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000r4000000) that shows how to convert annotations to polygons. Works well and I made it into an add-in for my own use. Once you have the polygons, you can easily copy and paste to a line feature class then export to DXF, DWG, Shapefile, etc. This will give you the OUTLINE of the text which works fine in 3rd party applications.  If what you have in mind is a line-based font such as those proprietary drafting fonts in autocad for example then I don't personally know of any way to do that. These are legacy fonts that are actually line drawings converted to a special autocad type font (shx).  There is no such equivalent in ArcGIS.